# Adding a computer player

Tags: java, swing, jframe

After finishing writing and appending the code for a one player version of Tron, I was wondering how I would a cpu player:

```
public class Tron{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Tron();
    }

    public Tron(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tron");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel{
        private int xVelocity;
        private int yVelocity;
        protected static final int PLAYER_SIZE = 0;
        protected static final int DELTA = 4;
        public static int timer = 0;
        private static List xList = new ArrayList();
        private static List yList = new ArrayList();

        private Point player;
        private Point lastTurn;
        private Path2D playerPath;
        private final Random random = new Random();

        public TestPane(){
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");

            am.put("left", new VelocityAction(-DELTA, 0));
            am.put("right", new VelocityAction(DELTA, 0));
            am.put("up", new VelocityAction(0, -DELTA));
            am.put("down", new VelocityAction(0, DELTA));
            xVelocity = DELTA;

            player = new Point(40, 40);
            lastTurn = new Point(player);
            playerPath = new Path2D.Float();
            playerPath.moveTo(40, 40);


            Timer playerTimer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    player.x += xVelocity;
                    if (player.x > getWidth()){
                        playerPath.lineTo(getWidth(), player.y);
                        playerPath.moveTo(0, player.y);
                        player.x = 0;
                        lastTurn = new Point(player);
                    }
                    if (player.x + PLAYER_SIZE < 0){
                        playerPath.lineTo(0, player.y);
                        playerPath.moveTo(getWidth() - 1, player.y);
                        player.x = getWidth() - 1;
                        lastTurn = new Point(player);
                    }
                    xList.add(player.x);
                    player.y += yVelocity;
                    if (player.y > getHeight()){
                        playerPath.lineTo(player.x, getHeight());
                        playerPath.moveTo(player.x, 0);
                        player.y = 0;
                        lastTurn = new Point(player);
                    }
                    if (player.y + PLAYER_SIZE < 0){
                        playerPath.lineTo(player.x, 0);
                        playerPath.moveTo(player.x, getHeight() - 1);
                        player.y = getHeight() - 1;
                        lastTurn = new Point(player);
                    }
                    yList.add(player.y);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            playerTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(playerPath);
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(lastTurn, player));
            g2d.drawRect(player.x - (PLAYER_SIZE / 2), player.y - (PLAYER_SIZE / 2), PLAYER_SIZE, PLAYER_SIZE);
        }

        public class VelocityAction extends AbstractAction{

            private final int xDelta;
            private final int yDelta;

            public VelocityAction(int xDelta, int yDelta){
                this.xDelta = xDelta;
                this.yDelta = yDelta;
            };
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                xVelocity = xDelta;
                yVelocity = yDelta;
                lastTurn = new Point(player);
                playerPath.lineTo(player.x, player.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried duplicating all the methods and declarations for the human player and adding a random number generator to determine which way it would turn, however the cpu would just kinda freak out and not even move in a straight line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A computer player does the same things as a human player. All you have to do is create a new player which calculates his moves, you don't have to duplicate anything.

Comment: *"I was wondering how I would (program) a cpu player:"*  Well, simply 1) Write down in words what you (as a human player) would do if **you** were the computer.  2) Translate that into code.  --  Now you might detect a slight note of sarcasm in that 2 point list.  That sarcasm is trying to express that it is not a trivial matter to program an AI to do something as simple as play (and win) Tron.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is not easy to do this. creating new methods, etc. for a cpu based of the player seemed like it would work at the time, but the cpu had a lot of graphical glitches when I did that, so I though maybe someone here could help with this. I don't really want to add logic to this yet, I just want a cpu that moves around randomly (the game has no boundaries yet)

Comment: Also I would like to just know some things about cpu's in general, like should I add a separate class for it, or do I just need to incorporate it's movement in already existing methods?